# Can't modify a cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to "flip" a cell in a UICollectionView when the user two-finger taps a cell.

I've added a gesture recognizer for two-touches, and a breakpoint in the target method shows that I've wired that part up correctly.

The target method at this stage just tries to add a subview to the cell, which should cover it with some different content, but nothing happens.

Am I trying to do something that I shouldn't?

Comment: Down vote my question? Who the heck does that sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

For Flip cell Use this code:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:cell.contentView
                                    toView:newView
                                  duration:.5
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                completion:nil];
```